# IndexError: list index out of range creating and opening a xlsx

Tags: python, xlsx

I want to make a program in python that creates an xlsx file that has a sheet for each letter. I want to read 150 files that have numbers and name separate for ":", for example "03005:stackoverflow" on each line, and put each number with its name in the sheet that starts with the first letter of the name.

When I execute my program it gives me this error and I don't know how to fix it. Not every time I execute it, it fails at the same interation.

```
import openpyxl
import tkinter, re
import xlwt
import os.path
def read_file(name,e,arrayPositions,fileName):
    f = open(name,"r",encoding="utf8")
    print("El fichero que estamos leyendo es "+name)
    for line in f.readlines():
            words = line.split(":")
            if (words[1])[0] is None:
                    if (words[1])[0] == "A":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("A")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[0],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[0],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[0]=arrayPositions[0]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "B":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("B")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[1],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[1],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[1]=arrayPositions[1]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "C":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("C")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[2],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[2],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[2]=arrayPositions[2]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "D":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("D")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[3],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[3],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[3]=arrayPositions[3]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "E":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("E")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[4],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[4],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[4]=arrayPositions[4]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "F":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("F")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[5],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[5],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[5]=arrayPositions[5]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "G":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("G")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[6],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[6],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[6]=arrayPositions[6]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "H":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("H")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[7],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[7],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[7]=arrayPositions[7]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "I":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("I")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[8],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[8],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[8]=arrayPositions[8]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "J":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("J")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[9],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[9],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[9]=arrayPositions[9]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "K":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("K")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[10],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[10],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[10]=arrayPositions[10]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "L":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("L")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[11],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[11],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[11]=arrayPositions[11]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "M":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("M")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[12],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[12],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[12]=arrayPositions[12]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "N":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("N")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[13],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[13],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[13]=arrayPositions[13]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "Ñ":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("Ñ")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[14],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[14],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[14]=arrayPositions[14]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "O":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("O")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[15],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[15],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[15]=arrayPositions[15]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "P":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("P")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[16],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[16],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[16]=arrayPositions[16]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "Q":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("Q")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[17],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[17],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[17]=arrayPositions[17]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "R":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("R")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[18],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[18],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[18]=arrayPositions[18]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "S":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("S")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[19],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[19],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[19]=arrayPositions[19]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "T":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("T")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[20],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[20],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[20]=arrayPositions[20]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "U":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("U")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[21],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[21],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[21]=arrayPositions[21]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "V":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("V")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[22],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[22],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[22]=arrayPositions[22]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "W":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("W")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[23],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[23],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[23]=arrayPositions[23]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "Y":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("Y")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[24],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[24],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[24]=arrayPositions[24]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "X":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("X")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[25],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[25],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[25]=arrayPositions[25]+1
                    if (words[1])[0] == "Z":
                            sheet = e.get_sheet("Z")
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[26],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                            sheet.write(arrayPositions[26],1,words[0])
                            arrayPositions[26]=arrayPositions[26]+1
   e.save(fileName)
   f.close()
   return arrayPositions


fileName = "aCode.xlsx"
e = xlwt.Workbook(fileName)
e.add_sheet("A")
e.add_sheet("B")
e.add_sheet("C")
e.add_sheet("D")
e.add_sheet("E")
e.add_sheet("F")
e.add_sheet("G")
e.add_sheet("H")
e.add_sheet("I")
e.add_sheet("J")
e.add_sheet("K")
e.add_sheet("L")
e.add_sheet("M")
e.add_sheet("N")
e.add_sheet("Ñ")
e.add_sheet("O")
e.add_sheet("P")
e.add_sheet("Q")
e.add_sheet("R")
e.add_sheet("S")
e.add_sheet("T")
e.add_sheet("U")
e.add_sheet("V")
e.add_sheet("W")
e.add_sheet("X")
e.add_sheet("Y")
e.add_sheet("Z")
arrayPositions = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

for x in range(1,150):
        arrayPositions = read_file(str(x)+".txt",e,arrayPositions, fileName)
```

Comment: Have you considered something like `sheet = e.get_sheet(words[1][0])`?

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, the problem of doing that is that a don't know how to indicate the correct position os arrayPositions, because of each letter, it refers to a diferent position.

Comment: Please include the actual error, and please consider creating a [mcve] that focus on the _minimum_ part. I'm guessing if you have this problem with 26 letters, you probably also have this problem with three or four letters.

Comment: The problem doens't appear with one specific letter and either with all the letters, it seems a little random. That's why I posted all the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have

`if (words[1])[0] is None:`

in your code and then you compare values of `words[1][0]` to some characters.

Did you mean to write

`if (words[1])[0] is not None:`

So, that if these values are not NoneType it will go to inner if and compare the value with characters

**UPDATE**

Of couse that would not solve your problem, as if list word does not have element [1] or words[1][0] does not have element it will give you index error. There are many ways to see if list with that index exists. But for you the easiest one would be to change `if (words[1])[0] is None:` with `try:` and write `except:` after the if statements. For example:

```
if (words[1])[0] is None:
                if (words[1])[0] == "A":
                        sheet = e.get_sheet("A")
                        sheet.write(arrayPositions[0],0,(words[1])[:-1])
                        sheet.write(arrayPositions[0],1,words[0])
                        arrayPositions[0]=arrayPositions[0]+1
                **all other ifs
```

to

```
try:
    if (words[1])[0] == "A":
        sheet = e.get_sheet("A")
        sheet.write(arrayPositions[0],0,(words[1])[:-1])
        sheet.write(arrayPositions[0],1,words[0])
        arrayPositions[0]=arrayPositions[0]+1
    ** All other if statements
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Of course! I wanted to do that. But I've added not and it still getting me the same error.